# Comparing two ways of getting sub-list length

Tags: python

I have two implementations of getting a sub-list length. There is a dramatic performance difference. I would like to know why.

```
import time

# list with 100000 integers
with open('IntegerArray.txt') as f:
    input_list = [int(x) for x in f.read().splitlines()]

i = 50000

start_1 = time.time()
len(input_list[i:])
print("--- %s seconds --- " % (time.time() - start_1))

start_2 = time.time()
len(input_list) -i
print("--- %s seconds --- " % (time.time() - start_2))
```

**Output:**

```
--- 0.000550985336304 seconds ---
--- 2.14576721191e-06 seconds ---
```

Why is this? Does this mean I have to avoid using the first method and use the second at all times?

Comment: I ran the test on my laptop with  input_list = list(range(10000)) and the time for each test was 0.0 seconds.  After setting input_list = list(range(1000000)), the first test took 0.015599966049194336 seconds and the second test took 0.0 seconds. My platform is Anaconca Python 3.4.3 on Windows 7 x64 with Intel Core i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz. What is your platform?

Comment: @TrisNefzger `10000` was a typo. I fixed it to `100000`. I am using OSX Yosemite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
len(input_list[i:])
```

This makes a copy of the list from position i to the end, an `O(n)` operation (where `n` is the number of elements in the *slice*). Then it asks it what its length is: `O(1)`. So `O(n)` overall.

```
len(input_list) -i
```

This is just asking for length (`O(1)`) and then subtracting (also `O(1)`). So `O(1)` overall.

See: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: I would add "Execution time is often irrelevant when choosing between unrepeated alternative sub-second operations. However, if repeated, it could matter.  Also the second form is easier to read."

Answer (score 3):

[NightShadeQueen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31767662/comparing-two-ways-of-getting-sub-list-length/31767700) is correct.

There is one additional detail: In the situation when `i` is greater than the length of the list, then `len(input_list[i:])` will be zero, but `len(input_list) - i` will be a negative number.

This is because the slice operator will limit the indexes to the endpoints of the array.